# Create a file in every subdirectory

Tags: ruby, file-io

I want to iterate through every subdirectory inside a directory (no need to iterate deeper than that) and create a file within each.

For example:

```
C:\
-C:\folder1
-C:\folder2
-...
```

I want to end up with a file in each of these folders:

```
C:\
-C:\folder1\file1.txt
-C:\folder2\file2.txt
-...
```

The code I've tried is

```
require 'securerandom'

array =[]

IO.foreach('output.txt') { |line|
  array<<line
}

array.each { |folder|
  randomName = SecureRandom.hex
  File.open("#{folder}\\#{randomName}.txt", 'wb+') do |f|
      buffer = ((SecureRandom.hex)*8).freeze
      randomNumber = (rand 1..9)
      randomNumber.kilobytes.times { f.write buffer }
  end
}
```

Where `output.txt` is a file with the full directory of all my desired folders, separated by newlines, e.g.:

**output.txt:**

```
"C:\Users\folder1"
"C:\Users\folder2"
...
```

As for `SecureRandom.hex`, I just need the contents and file sizes of the files to be random.

Thank you again for your kind help!

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as template:

```
i = 0
Dir['c:\*'].each do | subdir |
  next unless File.directory?(subdir)
  File.open("#{subdir}/file#{i}.txt", "w") { | io | io << 'foo' }
  i += 1
end
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea Dir[ ] even existed; thanks for your answer! This works just fine.